# Restarting build steps from the failure point on Hudson/jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, hudson, hudson-plugins

My requirement is , Say for example for a job on Jenkins/Hudson , i have configured three build steps which perform 3 separate tasks.
Step1: Execute shell script (echo $PATH)
Step2: Execute Shell Script (sgsh)
Step3: Execute shell Script (echo $JAVA_HOME)

IN these build steps say for example step 2 fails , I need a plugin which will allow me to restart the build from step2 since step1 is already completed successfully. Is there anything available?

Answer (score 0):

Check [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) . With [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) it do what you want.